# Rails-5, Unknown command nifty-generators

Tags: ruby-on-rails, macos, terminal

I am trying to add a Gem into my Gemfile and generate the layout file, the command is
**gem 'nifty-generators', :group => :development**

However, when I type this command in the terminal, the feedback is
**ERROR:  While executing gem ... (Gem::CommandLineError) Unknown command nifty-generators**

How should I fix it?

Answer (score 0):

You don't type that in your terminal, you'll need to add it to your `Gemfile` and then run `bundle install` from the terminal.